# Dúvida o $group mongodb

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb

Estou precisando usar o operador de agrupamento `$group` do mongodb, porém toda explicação que eu encontro é muito confusa.

Como funciona isso e qual o benefício de usar esse operador?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `$group` é um dos estágios do `aggregate`. A ideia do `aggregate` é estabelecer uma pipeline de operações sobre uma collection que vai produzir uma saída determinada. É uma alternativa ao `map-reduce` oferecida pelo MongoDB. [Na documentação sobre `aggregation` do MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#stage-operators), o uso do `aggregate` é descrito em pseudo-código como:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { <stage> }, ... ])
```

Ou seja, `db.collection.aggregate` recebe um array de `stage`s, estágios no pipeline (como o `$group`). Existem vários estágios descritos nesse link acima. O mais simples, seria o `$match`, que simplesmente filtra os resultados no momento em que passam por ele para o próximo estágio do pipeline. Por exemplo:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { nome: 'Wallace' } },
  { $match: { idade: 10 } }
])
```

Vai primeiro filtrar todos os documentos pelo field `nome` e em seguida pelo field `idade`. Note que isso poderia ser redundante e mais lento do que se só executassemos `{ $match: { nome: 'Wallace', idade: 10 } }`, mas [o MongoDB realiza otimizações no pipeline que você definir e uma delas combina vários `$match`s seguidos em um](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#match-match-coalescence).

Quanto ao `$group`, a ideia é passar um field `_id`, que define como você quer agrupar os resultados do seu pipeline e vários fields que trabalhem sobre todos os documentos gerando algum resultado final. Por exemplo:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  { $match: { nome: 'Wallace' } },
  { $group: { _id: '$idade', total: { $sum: 1 } } }
})
```

Vai primeiro filtrar todos os documentos, encontrando aqueles com `doc.nome == 'Wallace'` e em seguida os agrupar por `idade`. Assim, todos os grupos de documentos com a mesma idade vão ser representados por um único objeto, com o formato:

```
{ 
  _id: <alguma-idade>,
  total: <0 + 1 para cada documento agrupado (portanto: o total de Wallaces com essa idade)>
}
```

O `$sum` acima é um operador do estágio `$group`. Ele leva algum parâmetro, que pode ser calculado para cada documento, e produz a soma de todos os resultados para todos os documentos. Se escrevêssemos:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$nome', somaDasIdades: { $sum: '$idade' } } }
])
```

Receberíamos a soma de todas as idades para cada grupo de documentos com o mesmo nome.

A lista completa de operadores para produzir resultados no estágio `$group` está aqui:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator.

O valor que fica ao lado do `_id` ou do `$sum` é qualquer expressão válida, então ele pode ser:

- um valor literal, como `'Wallace'`
- um caminho até um campo nos documentos que estão passando `'$documento.campo'`
- um objeto que aplica várias expressões para campos específicos

Um exemplo usando um objeto como `_id` seria:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        nome: '$nome',
        idade: '$idade'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Isso vai criar grupos (sem outros campos fora o `_id`) de todos os documentos com a mesma `idade` e o mesmo `nome`.

Também existe uma função no REPL `db.collection.group`, mas ela é só um helper para fazer `aggregate`s só com um estágio `$group`.

Acho que isso dá a noção básica que é possível se passar rapidamente. Eu sugiro fortemente que você leia a documentação do `aggregate` que eu linkei acima:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/

Sobre o porquê de se usar um `aggregate`, acho que depende extremamente do que você for fazer. Assim como o `map-reduce`, esse é o tipo de operação a ser feita quando a quantidade de dados sobre a qual você está operando é grande o suficiente para não valer a pena os processar no código da sua aplicação. Nesses casos, usar algo como um `aggregate` vai ser mais (muito mais) eficiente do que puxar uma quantidade grande de dados para sua aplicação e os tratar nela.